# replacement rule to pull independent expression outside of Integrate

Tags: pattern-matching

I'm trying to write a fairly general replacement rule that will pull expressions independent of the variable of integration outside of Integrate, since `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` do not seem to do this.

So as an example I try

```
Integrate[f[x] Log[y], {x, r, s}] /.
 Integrate[q_*r_, {v_, l_, h_}] /; FreeQ[r, v] -> 
  r*Integrate[q, {v, l, h}]
```

and that returns

```
(* (-r f[x] + s f[x]) Log[y] *)
```

Trace shows it correctly recognized the Log as independent of z and pulled it outside but then, even though it recognizes that f[x] depends on x, it incorrectly does the integration and finally assembles the result.

If `f[x]` is previously defined, say `Sin[x]`, then this problem does not appear.

Is there a way to write this rule that would be correct in all circumstances?

Answer (score 6):

The problem there is that you are using an immediate rule instead of a delayed rule. So, even before looking at your expression, *Mathematica* evaluates

```
r*Integrate[q, {v, l, h}]
```

to

```
(h - l) q r
```

The replacement it is doing is actually

```
Integrate[q_*r_, {v_, l_, h_}] /; FreeQ[r, v] -> (h - l) q r
```

Try

```
Integrate[f[x] Log[y], {x, r, s}] /.
 Integrate[q_*r_, {v_, l_, h_}] /; FreeQ[r, v] :> 
  r*Integrate[q, {v, l, h}]
```

and you get

```
(* Integrate[f[x], {x, r, s}]*Log[y] *)
```