# Pulling constants out of integrations

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The following is the code and output of a Mathematica command
[image]

How do I get Mathematica to remove $g(y)$ outside the integral?

Comment: Interestingly Integrate knows there is no dependency, `g[y] Integrate[1/g[y]] -> x `. Anyone try to tackle this through `Simplify[ .. ComplexityFunction .. ]` ??

Comment: @Micheal E2 Actually, this is not a duplicate, but a more general question that opens up ways different from replacement rules to solve the problem, as the answer by george2079 shows. I wonder if it would be possible to merge posts so that the more general question can be posed along with special cases...

Comment: Oops. It was @Michael E2, not Micheal. Sorry. (Somehow autocompletion of "@" names is no longer working on this PC...)

Comment: @Dilaton - I'm extremely interested. Its just what I've been looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is some code I adapted from a package I wrote to manipulate `Sum`s, instead of integrals. But it should work in bringing out expression that do not depend on the integration variable too. After all, integrals are sums pushed to the limit.
EDIT: cleaned up code, there is no need to separate rules here.

> ```
> outrules = {
>            Integrate[f_ + g_, it:{x_Symbol, __}] :> Integrate[f, it] + Integrate[g, it],
>            Integrate[c_ f_, it:{x_Symbol, __}] :> c Integrate[f, it] /; FreeQ[c, x],
>            Integrate[c_, it:{x_Symbol, __}] :> c Integrate[1, it] /; FreeQ[c, x]
>            };
> ```

(You could apply the rules directly as in `expr //. outrules`, but I like to define an ordinary procedure like `BringOut` - or `PullOut` if you prefer)

> ```
> BringOut[s_] := s //. outrules
> ```

It works in your simple example

```
g[y] Integrate[f[x1, y]/g[y], {x1, 0, x}] // BringOut

    (* Integrate[f[x1, y], {x1, 0, x}] *)
```

and it also works with more complex integrands (basically, it exploits the linear property of the integral)

```
Integrate[y(f[x1, y]/(1 + g[y]) - h[y]), {x1, 0, x}] // BringOut

    (* y (Integrate[f[x1, y], {x1,0,x}]/(1 + g[y]) - x h[y]) *)
```

Sometimes you might want to wrap and `Expand`, or an `Apart` or some other expression manipulation procedure to the integrand. Since the action usually depends on the expression, I found no use into incorporating this into `BringOut`. It's cleaner to apply the desired simplification where you need it and only when you need it, usually after `BringOut` has done its work:

```
BringOut[Integrate[y(f[x1, y]/(1 + g[y]) - h[y]), {x1, 0, x}]] // Factor

    (* (Integrate[f[x1, y], {x1,0,x}] - x h[y] + x g[y] h[y]) y / (1 + g[y]) *)
```

Caveat emptor: the original code worked on a user defined and unevaluated version of `Sum`, and I have not tested it thoroughly with a built-in procedure like `Integrate`. But I do not see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: (+1) Nice Answer. You have an extra semi-colon at the end of `outrules` list after `FreeQ`.

Comment: @H.R., thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Do you have a way to match the pattern when there are several integration variables? So you would need to match several instances of {x_Symbol, __} but also track the symbol names x so that they can be used in FreeQ

Answer (score 2):

Based on this solution ([replacement rule to pull independent expression outside of Integrate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14616/replacement-rule-to-pull-independent-expression-outside-of-integrate)) You can solve it the following way:

```
g[y]*Integrate[f[x1, y]/g[y], {x1, 0, x}] /.Integrate[q_/r_, {v_, l_, h_}] 
/; FreeQ[r, v] :> 1/r*Integrate[q, {v, l, h}]
```

> Integral[f[x1, y],{x1,0,x}]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a *stab* at the problem using TransformationFunctions:

```
ClearAll[xx]
xx[exp_Integrate /; 
       Head[integrand = (First@(List @@ exp))] == Times ] := Module[{dep,indep},
    indep = 
      Select[(List @@ integrand), (FreeQ[#, First@(Last@(List @@ exp))]) &] ;
    dep = Complement[(List @@ integrand), indep];
    ((Times @@ indep ) Integrate[Times @@ dep, (Last@(List @@ exp))])];
xx[exp_] := exp
Simplify[g[y] Integrate[ g[x]/g[y] , {x, 0, 1}],  TransformationFunctions -> {xx}]

(*  Integrate[ g[x] , {x, 0, 1}] *)
```

Big UNTESTED warning.. I only checked that it works for the given example..

Also adding Automatic to TransformationFunctions breaks it for some reason I havent explored