# How to symbolically solve the minimization problem in simple linear regression

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, symbolic

I want to use mathematica to symbolically solve the minimization problem in simple linear regression:

$${\text{Find }}\text{arg}\min _{\alpha ,\,\beta }Q(\alpha ,\beta ),\qquad {\text{for }}Q(\alpha ,\beta ) =\sum _{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}-\alpha -\beta x_{i})^{2},$$

where $y_i$, $x_i$, and $n$ are symbolic but not specific numbers.The expected answer would be something like

$$\begin{align}
\hat {\beta }&={\frac {\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-{\bar {x}})(y_{i}-{\bar {y}})}{\sum _{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-{\bar {x}})^{2}}},\\
{\hat {\alpha }}&={\bar {y}}-{\hat {\beta }}\,{\bar {x}}
\end{align}$$

Can someone show some code example for doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks Michael for your suggestions!

Comment: See [(107426)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/107426/27951).

Comment: What have you done so far? People are more likely to help if you show effort.

Comment: You're welcome.  Maybe someone else can help with your question.  My experience has been that *Mathematica's* facility with algebraic/symbolic sums is limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is an adaptation of [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107442/27951) to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/107426/27951), which focused on the 3D linear least-squares problem.

```
(* Rules to get constants out of sums (or integrals etc) *)
outrules = {
   Sum[f_ + g_, it : {x_Symbol, __}] :> Sum[f, it] + Sum[g, it],
   Sum[c_ f_, it : {x_Symbol, __}] :> c Sum[f, it] /; FreeQ[c, x],
   Sum[c_, it : {x_Symbol, __}] :> c Sum[1, it] /; FreeQ[c, x]
   };

(*Generate the sum of squares*)
Sum[Expand[(y[i] - a x[i] - b)^2], {i, 1, n}];

(*Calculate the derivatives*)
Grad[%, {a, b}];

(*Use the linearity property of sums*)
Distribute /@ %;

(*Pull out any constants from summations*)
% //. outrules;

(*Set the derivatives equal to zero to generate a system of equations*)
Simplify[Thread[% == 0]];

(*Solve for the a, b parameters*)
Solve[%, {a, b}] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

These sums are not yet expressed as a function of $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$, i.e. the average values of the $(x_i,y_i)$, respectively, as you have them in your question, but that should be a question of some algebraic transformations. Some such transformations are reported e.g. in [this MathWorld document](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html) of least-squares fitting.